# Trying to get property 'rank' of non-object in

Tags: php

I have this json data:

```
$my_data = '[
   {
      "rank":"4",
      "logo":"",
      "team":"FCB",
      "pld":"29",
      "won":"14",
      "draw":"6",
      "lost":"9",
      "left":"5",
      "minus":"30:44",
      "diff":"14",
      "pts":"48",
      "date":"Dec. 31st 69"
   }
]';
```

I wanted to get "rank" value using this code:

```
$data_get =  json_encode($my_data );
echo $data_get->rank;
```

i get this error

> Trying to get property 'rank' of non-object in

Comment: Do you mean `json_decode`?

Comment: Wouldn't it be `echo $data_get[0]->rank`?